# Image download failed with url iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to download my image and store into a directory. Every thing is working fine before updating the names of images on the server end with spaces. I am handling the spaces with the following code.

```
NSString *newString = [getImageUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                                             withString:@"%20"];
```

After that I am getting the final String of URL as given below

http://www.retail-king.com/image/data/men%20jeans/pd%201/5.jpg

When I open this url in browser then the image is showing but I cannot see and download the image with this url in the app.

I am calling the following method to download the image.

```
-(void)downloadImageWithPath:(NSString *)_path andURL:(NSString *)_url
```

{

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_url]];

NSLog(@"pic file = %@",_path);
NSLog(@"ASI http pic url:%@",[[request url] description]);


//    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground=YES;

[request setDownloadDestinationPath:_path];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
//    [request setDelegate:self];
[request setStartedBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"request started pic");
}];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSLog(@"request completed pic");
    currentPicsCount++;
    if (currentPicsCount == picsCount && totalPicsDownload ) {
        NSLog(@"All pics have downloaded");
        totalPicsDownload = false;
        [[SingltonClass getLoadingClassReference] dataSynced];

    }
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"request failed pic");
    picsCount--;
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

}
  setFailedBlock is called. Which shows pic is failed to download.

Comment: Please share some code that shows how you're making the HTTP request for the image. Also, tell us what kind of HTTP error code (or exception, or whatever) that you're seeing in your app.

Comment: Hi @Aaron,
I have added the method in my asked question. By which I am downloading the image and save into the given directory.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a new project I would quickly run away from `ASIHTTPRequest` as it's an old unsupported library.

Comment: @Paul.s yes this is a new project which I am developing in xcode5. Instead of ASIHTTPRequest what can you recommend?

Comment: The native API's should have you covered perfectly these days but if you want some of the boiler plate removed you could look at something like AFNetworking

Comment: @Paul.s I don't think that this issue is due to ASIHTTPRequest because it was working fine a day before.

Comment: I didn't say it was an issue - I'm just saying that you should 100% not be using that library for new projects

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. I quickly ran a test on the URL and was able to see the downloaded image. This might not be an ideal solution, but you can understand what's going on. I used `UIWebView` to display the image, and the for you the tricky part could be to set the bounds of `CGRectMake`. How are you downloading and displaying the images?

Here is my code if it helps.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Added space between keyword men and jeans
    NSString *url = @"http://retail-king.com/image/data/men jeans/pd%201/5.jpg";
    url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

    // Check for URL
    NSLog(@"Final Url = %@",url);

    // Displaying it on webview
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    // Program to check if the image is downloaded in directory

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *localFilePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSData *thedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [thedata writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];

}
```

The image was successfully downloaded at -

```
/Users/raurora/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/554A5C94-1D29-42F0-886D-751CD3DFB155/Library/Caches/com.stackoverflow.doubt/fsCachedData/
```